# IE 9 won't install on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I tried to install IE 9 on my machine but it request for Windows6.1-KB2454826-v2-x64 update but when I download the patch, it won't install either. It status could remain "Searching for updates on your computer" for ages if left alone. There's hardly a suggested solutions that I haven't tried.

Comment: Are you installing using Windows Updates, or the web installer?

Comment: I'm using window updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try [downloading IE9 from the Microsoft Website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie), see if this will install.

.